# Can't declare serial port using qextserialport

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qextserialport

I have seen several questions and googled a lot and I can't find a way to declare a serial port object using qextserialport, in order to read and write to/from an arduino. I tried what the user did in [How to write on serial port using Qextserialport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274887/how-to-write-on-serial-port-using-qextserialport), but the compiler gives me the following error:

```
undefined reference to `QextSerialPort::QextSerialPort(QString const&, QextSerialPort::QueryMode, QObject*)'
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QtExtSerialPort/qextserialport.h>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_BTN_Connect_clicked()
{

    int index=ui->Selector_Port->currentIndex();
    QextSerialPort *port = new QextSerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0");
}
```

Why does this error appear? I'm using Debian 8.2 and QT 4.8.6

**EDIT:**
After adding the lines:

```
CONFIG += qesp_linux_udev
QT += extserialport
```

to the project file, I'm having the following error:

```
"Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: extserialport"
```

Comment: Do you have a line `QT += extserialport` in your `.pro` file? Do you use it as a Qt module or include project directly in `.pro` include(qextserialport/src/qextserialport.pri) ?

Comment: Yes, this line is in the project file, but it's not working.

Comment: It is a linker error. It means that it cannot find binaries with implementation of `QextSerialPort`.

Comment: How can I find the binaries?

Comment: And by the way, to the ones that have down voted: Can you please explain precisely why you are down voting?

Comment: @ It depends how you integrated it. It can be compiled as a separate library or it is possible to include directly sources with `qextserialport.pri` into your main project, so everything can be compiled as single application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is generated by linker. It means that it cannot find `QextSerialPort` library binaries.

According to [QextSerialPort Manual](http://docs.qextserialport.googlecode.com/git-history/3c714140fc7d5d85077626d8e22d8582ff105d2f/2.0/index.html) `QextSerailPort` in Qt4 can be used only in *Compat Mode*:

> Can be used as static or shared library, or simply integrate the
>   component into application.

The simplest solution is just to build `QextSerailPort` together with your main project. Just include it to your project file (`.pro`):

```
include(pathToQesp/compat/qextserialport.pri)
```

---

You do not need `QT += extserialport`, since in the *Compat Mode* it is not used as a Qt module.

---

**The simplest HowTo**

- create a new folder; go to it: `mkdir test && cd test`
- `git clone https://github.com/qextserialport/qextserialport`
- create a new Qt project in this folder, for example with name `extserialtest`, so you have two folders:

  - `qextserialport` with `QextSerailPort` package
  - `extserialtest` with your Qt project
- add the line `include (../qextserialport/src/qextserialport.pri)` into `extserialtest.pro`
- write your project code: `#include <qextserialport.h>` and `new QextSerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0");`

Verified on Qt 4.8.3 in Linux that it works out of the box.

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you very much for your detailed answer ;)